# Unity can not debug using MonoDevelop. And, UnityEngine is not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am using Unity 5.4.1f1 Japanese version.
I installed Visual Stduio 2015 Community and Visual Studio Tool.
But, I wanted to return to MonoDevelop, I uninstalled Unity and Visual Studio.
And I installed Unity again.

After that, when I press the play button on the top left of MonoDevelope, the following error will be displayed.
And I can not start debugging.

```
PATH\Assembly-CSharp.csproj(22,22): Error MSB4066: 要素 <ProjectExtensions> の属性 "xmlns" は認識されていません。 (MSB4066) (Assembly-CSharp)
```

Also, the UnityEngine namespace will not load with the following error.

```
error CS0103: The name `UnityEngine' does not exist in the current context
```

All GameObjects and MonoBehaviours in the source code are displayed as errors.
However, only MonoDevelop gives an error. I can run games on Unity.
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.
I was setting the `Code Formatting` option of the assembly.
Then, it seems that the csproj file contains tags that MonoDevelop can not read.
When setting `Code Formatting` in the project option, the error disappeared.